# I got bigquery - DML cannot update view 'mydateset.myview'

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-warehouse

I would like to make a query on google bigquery and schedule it as a simple pipeline. What I've made is I first made a query with a couple of CTEs and save the view, then modify the query as

```
INSERT INTO mydataset.myview
With t1 AS (...),
t2 AS (...),
...
big_t AS (...)
SELECT * FROM big_t t2
WHERE t2.date > (SELECT MAX(date) FROM mydataset.myview)
```

but, when I click the `run_query` button, I got the prompt warning tells

DML cannot update view 'mydateset.myview'

I don't know why, because I think there is nothing to do with the syntax

is that to do with the way I save the view or something else?

Comment: Is `mydataset.myview` really a VIEW? You can only insert data to table, not a view.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that it is about the table vs view manipulation. So, the INSERT/SELECT only works on table, when I change the query to be create table first the INSERT/SELECT, it works.

Answer (score 0):

To update view you need to use [`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_view_statement) DDL

Answer (score 0):

You can update data in a table only or a materialized view but not in a view.